# How can I check the distance between two latitude and longitude coorindates?

Tags: java, android, android-location

I'm fetching the user's best current position using this snippet:

```
    LocationManager ltrLocationer = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    Location locLocation = ltrLocationer.getLastKnownLocation(ltrLocationer.getBestProvider(criteria, true));
```

I have a two `Double` objects containing a latitude and a longitude respectively. I'd like to check the distance in metres between the current coordinates and the the aforementioned value. How can I do this?

This sounded like a pretty simple thing to accomplish but I haven't been able to find an example illustrating this. Thanks.

Comment: You're right. I suggested it be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Location object has a distance method.  Use that, it does the math for you.  If you have your coordinates as douboles, use the static function Location.distanceBetween

Answer (score 1):

take a look here :[GPS Coordinates to Meters](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)
Also here is a wikipedia article about the equation used to do the calculations: [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Answer (score 0):

Check this method, this will give you the `distance in a straight line`.

```
public static double distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
double earthRadius = 3958.75;
double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
double sindLat = Math.sin(dLat / 2);
double sindLng = Math.sin(dLng / 2);
double a = Math.pow(sindLat, 2) + Math.pow(sindLng, 2)
        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2));
double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
double dist = earthRadius * c;

return dist;
}
```

If you want a `road distance` this operation is a little bit more difficult and will involve a call to `Google Direction API` services.